# hide previous button only when the page number is zero and next button only when page number is 20

Tags: iphone, ios, button, hide, conditional-statements

I have two buttons with objects `*tmpltLeft` and `*tmpltRight`. When i launch my app, i want the previous button(`tmpltLeft`) initially to be hidden and when i press the next button(`tmpltRight`) i want the previous button(`tmpltLeft`) to be displayed and when the next button(`tmpltRight`) reaches page 20(last page) I want the next button(`tmpltRight`) to be hidden.

I have in .h file

```
IBOutlet UIButton *tmpltLeft, *tmpltRight;
```

In .m file

```
-(IBAction)templateNavigationBtnTapped:(UIButton*)sender {
UIButton *button=sender;
switch (button.tag) {
    case 1:
        NSLog(@"prev btn tapped");
        if (pageNo>1) {
            pageNo--;
        }    
        break;
    case 2:
        NSLog(@"next btn tapped");
        if (pageNo<18) {
           pageNo++;
       }
     break;
     default:
     break;
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Just check the pageNo value and set button.hidden to yes or no as necessary...

Comment: The answers can give you the general idea but try to use the `button.hidden` code after the switch

Comment: @Vikr: Have you solved the Problem ?

Comment: @Vin Thanks. Found out the answer. Your code makes the tmpltLeft Button hide when the PageNo is 1. But tmpltRight wont hide when it reaches the last page(i.e pageno = 18). I have copied the working code down.

Comment: @Vikr: Actually, you never told me that yourLast Page is "18". Just Read your Question again.I updated my Answer. And If you get the Answer, mark it as "Accepted", So it can help Future Visitors.

Comment: @Vin Thanks again. Yes i have mentioned 20 as the last page. Sorry about that, had to remove 2 pages later today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Set `[tmpltLeft setHidden:YES];` in `-viewDidLoad`

```
 -(IBAction)templateNavigationBtnTapped:(UIButton*)sender {
    UIButton *button=sender;
    switch (button.tag) {
        case 1:
            NSLog(@"prev btn tapped");
            if (pageNo>1) {
                [tmpltRight setHidden:NO];
                pageNo--;
                if (pageNo == 1)
                {
                     [tmpltLeft setHidden:YES];
                }
            }    
            break;
        case 2:
            NSLog(@"next btn tapped");
            [tmpltLeft setHidden:NO];
            if (pageNo<18) {
               pageNo++;
               if (pageNo == 18)
               {
                    [tmpltRight setHidden:YES];
               }
           }
         break;
         default:
         break;
    }
```

Not Implemented , but write here to get some Idea to you...

Answer (score 0):

You can check the page number and then hide the button. As per your code:

```
-(IBAction)templateNavigationBtnTapped:(UIButton*)sender {
    UIButton *button=sender;
    switch (button.tag) {
    case 1:
        NSLog(@"prev btn tapped");
        tmpltRight.hidden = NO; // for the next button in the last-1 page to be displayed if the page number is less than max number of pages. 
        if (pageNo>1) {
            pageNo--;
        } 
        else if (pageNo == 0)
           tmpltLeft.hidden = YES;
        break;
    case 2:
        NSLog(@"next btn tapped");
        tmpltLeft.hidden = NO; //for the previous button to be displayed when the page number is greater than 0.
        if (pageNo<18) {
           pageNo++;
        }
        else if (pageNo == 19)
            tmpltRight.hidden = YES;
        break;
    default:
        break;
   }
```

The code is not tested, but that is the general idea.

Comment: Initially tmpltLeft needs to be hidden before tapping any buttons and that can be done in viewDidLoad or in XIB, other than that, this should work.

Comment: Yeah, assuming it was done in one of `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear:` methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    BtnCount = 0;
    previosButton.enabled = FALSE;
}
-(IBAction)previosButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    BtnCount= BtnCount-1;
    if(BtnCount==0){
        previosButton.enabled=FALSE;
    }
    if(BtnCount<19){
        nextButton.enabled= TRUE;
    }
}
-(IBAction)nextButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    previosButton.enabled = TRUE;
    BtnCount = BtnCount+1;
    if(BtnCount==19)
    {
        nextButton.enabled = FALSE;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Its more suitable to handle any other additional conditions. And use .enabled property than hiding.

Answer (score 0):

```
   switch(button.tag) { case 1:
        NSLog(@"prev btn tapped");
        if (pageNo>1 || (tmpltLeft.hidden=TRUE)) {
            tmpltRight.hidden=FALSE;
            pageNo--;
            if(pageNo==1)
            tmpltLeft.hidden=TRUE;
           }
        break;
    case 2:
        NSLog(@"next btn tapped");

        if (pageNo<18 || (tmpltRight.hidden=TRUE)) {
            tmpltLeft.hidden=FALSE;
            pageNo++;
            if(pageNo==18)
                tmpltRight.hidden=TRUE;
        }
        break;
        default:
        break;
}
```

Initially tmpltLeft button is hidden in

- (void)viewDidLoad {

// Template Navigation Button

```
tmpltLeft.hidden=TRUE;
```

}